# Create a new amended column from an existing one (substring or regexp)

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for the best way in Oracle SQL to create a new column in a query where I remove & ignore any characters after the last forward slash "/".

I'll create the new column (NEW_COL_1) with a case statement but not sure of the best way to filter the text FROM COL1. See example below

```
Col_1   |   New_Col_1
---------------------
abc/ab  |   abc
a1/a1   |   a1
a1/a1/a2|   a1/a1
efg/a1/z|   efg/a1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it using `regexp_substr`.

```
select regexp_substr(col_1,'(.*)/.*$',1,1,null,1) as new_col_1
from tablename
where instr(col_1,'/') > 0
```

`(.*)/.*$` -- Get all characters until the last `/` in the string as the first group and extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions, you may use:

```
with test(s) as (
  select 'abc/ab  ' from dual union all
  select 'a1/a1   ' from dual union all
  select 'a1/a1/a2' from dual union all
  select 'efg/a1/z' from dual union all
  select 'efg'      from dual                /* no slash in the string */
)
select s, substr(s, 1,
                        case /* to handle the case no slash exists in the string */
                            when instr(s, '/', -1) = 0 then length(s)
                            else instr(s, '/', -1) -1
                        end
                )
from test
```

that gives:

```
abc/ab      abc
a1/a1       a1
a1/a1/a2    a1/a1
efg/a1/z    efg/a1
efg efg
```

The [`INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/INSTR.htm)is used to find the last occurrence of a slash ( the -1 parameter ) and the substring simply trims the string as needed.

This can be re-written in a more compact way as follows, according to Mathguy's suggestion:

```
select s,
       case
        when instr(s, '/') > 0 then substr(s, 1, instr(s, '/', -1) -1)
        else s 
       end
from test
```

The idea here is to only call functions if there is at least a slash in the string, simply returning the string itself if there's no slash.

Comment: or even: `select s, case when instr(...) > 0 then substr(s, 1, instr(...)-1) else s end`. Avoiding a `substr` and a `length` call when there are no slashes in the string.

Comment: @mathguy: and even clearer to read. Waiting for you to post the answer

Comment: Lol - no, if anything I would edit your post (it's your answer, this is just a minor change). Will let you do the work! (...And we don't even know if strings without slashes are possible in the OP's inputs!)

Answer (score 0):

Or using regular string functions; the instr gets the position of the first / counting backwards:

```
with data as
( select 'abc/ab' as col1 from dual union all
  select 'a1/a1' as col1 from dual union all
  select 'a1/a1/a2' as col1 from dual union all
  select 'efg/a1/z' as col1 from dual
)
select col1, instr( col1, '/',-1 ), substr( col1, 1, instr( col1, '/', -1 ) -1 )  from data
```

Result:

```
COL1     INSTR(COL1,'/',-1) SUBSTR(COL1,1,INSTR(COL1,'/',-1)
-------- ------------------ --------------------------------
abc/ab                    4 abc
a1/a1                     3 a1
a1/a1/a2                  6 a1/a1
efg/a1/z                  7 efg/a1
```

Comment: This will work OK if all input strings have at least one slash (as in the OP's sample input), but it won't work if there are no slashes. For such cases, it is worth at least asking the OP if that is possible in his/her data or not.

Comment: @mathguy. Yup, good point. I could modify the function to leave the string as is, if there are no slashes... decode( instr( col1, '/',-1 ), 0, col1, substr( col1, 1, instr( col1, '/', -1 ) -1 ) )